# How to generate vulkan project so it is cross-platform? (Using CMake)

Tags: c++, cmake, vulkan

So recently I have been using CMake to generate projects. I have dealt with libraries like `glfw` already, and I basically installed `source files` and compiled them into static libraries using CMake so that any potential user can compile that to his platform. But unlike glfw, I had no luck in finding source files for `vulkan SDK`. Instead it comes with already precompiled `.lib` files which to my understanding is windows specific. I'd like to know what is the best way to include vulkan in my project so that it truly is, a cross-platform library. And if posible, make it so it can all be handled by the build system.

Am also kinda new to C++ so please take that in mind. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindVulkan.html and let your users install the vilkan sdk themselves